# Persisting user login credentials

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angular6

I am using Firebase email and password authentication in my Angular 6 project,  and want to persist the user login credentials for a browser session.

Once a user is logged in and I press F5 the user appears to no longer be logged in.

looking at the firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence),  I should be able to set the persistence for the session by calling the method -

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION))
```

any idea where this code should go to properly implement this please?

```
_loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
constructor(
    public _fireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    _fireAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            this._loggedIn = true;
            console.log("onAuthStateChanged = true ");
        } else {
            console.log("onAuthStateChanged false ");
            this._loggedIn = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. Are you sure you don't have a faulty guard or something?

Comment: Along the same lines as Chrillewoodz's comment - you shouldn't need that setPersistance() line... and I can't spot anything wrong with the code you've added. What do you mean by `the user appears to no longer be logged in`? How are you determining that? I suspect it could either be a UI issue (*they actually are signed in and your UI hasn't updated*) or something funky going on with how you are listening to that BehaviorSubject.